# Hyphenation in list of figures

Tags: hyphenation, tocloft

I am trying to remove hyphenated words from my list of figures and tables and I've no real idea how to do it. I just don't like the look of the same words broken at different points. For example Temper-ature and Temp-erature

Is there a quick and east way to do this?

Cheers

Comment: Which version of English features a hyphenation point for `temperature` after `temp`?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: You state that in at least one case in your document the word "temperature" gets hyphenated after "temp". I was just curious which dialect of English (British? Australian?) would allow hyphenation point after "temp"...

Comment: I don't think I state which dialect of English I am using. Just \usepackage[english]{babel}

Comment: You probably get `tem-perature`. If you have long captions, you should consider using the optional argument: `\caption[<short>]{<long>}`; the `<short>` text will be typeset in the list of figures or tables. A very detailed caption doesn't make much sense if the table or figure is not available to look at.

Answer (score 6):

you can bury the list of figures or tables in a group, and turn off hyphenation entirely
within the group:

```
\begingroup
\hyphenpenalty10000
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\endgroup
```

there might be some overly-stretched lines or overfull boxes as a result, but
it's really hard to say for sure without knowing what document class you're using.

the `tocloft` manual does give this hint (p.5):

> To have the (sectional) titles in the ToC, etc., typeset ragged right with no
>   hyphenation
>
> ```
> \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}
> ```
>
> where the value `2.55em` can be changed for whatever margin space you want.

You need to wrap it in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` like this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I'm using the scrreprt document class. Overly-stretched lines aren't going to look good are they?

Comment: personal opinion -- overly stretched lines *never* look good.  the ragged right approach suggested in the manual appears to address this.

Comment: how do I change this command (\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}) for the LoF? I've just put it in as "\renewcommand{\@lofrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}"

Comment: if a command name has an `@` in it, you need to put `\makeatletter` before it, and `\makeatletter` after it.  that allows the `@` sign to be treated temporarily as a letter, so it can be part of a command name.

Comment: Hi Barbara - I tried this \makeatletter \renewcommand{\@lofrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil} \makeatother  But it didn't work. Latex error \@lofrmarg undefined

Comment: it may be that `tocloft` uses `\@tocmarg` for all such lists, not just specifically the toc.  i don't use `tocloft` myself, so i don't know for sure.  but since the toc is present in a document more often than the other lists, "parsimony" might be in operation here; besides, the manual did say "etc.".

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\mbox` command like this `\mbox{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}`

Comment: Is there not a global method. I have a thesis full of figures. Would I have to put \mbox around all my figure captions for example, or how do I use this?

Comment: You can add in the preamble all the words you don't want to be hyphenated, with the command \hyphenation{word}

Comment: @pablos -- putting a hyphenation list in the preamble affects the whole document, not just the prelims, and that may not be desirable.